# Building a docker container: will it be public?

Tags: docker

I want to build a Docker container from a Dockerfile. It contains a private project.

My question is quite simple, and I don't find a clear answer: after having built my image, will it be automatically sent as a public one on Docker repository?

I want to build this container for private use and it's not intended to be retrieved on the public Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker build -f Dockerfile` is a local operation.

You *can* `docker push` an image onto Dockerhub, but that is a separate operation and requires a Dockerhub account.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not automatically be published anywhere.

If you push the image onto Docker Hub, then it would be public unless you marked that repository private. (You get one private repository for free, though you can have more than one if you [pay for an account](https://hub.docker.com/account/billing-plans/).)